# Why does a token starting with '=' change semantics of a command in zsh?

Tags: zsh

The following shell command requires no explanation

```
a=1
```

However, when an extra space is added, zsh gives an unexpected error

```
a =1
zsh: 1 not found
```

Could someone explain this, please? What is the meaning of '=' is zsh?

Bash produces an error that I expected:

```
a =1
bash: a: command not found
```

Comment: Why the "linux" and "shell" tags? I'd even question the "bash" one, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fine manual says:

> #### '`=`' expansion
>
> If a word begins with an unquoted '`=`' and the `EQUALS` option     is
> set, the remainder of the word is taken as the  name  of      a
> command.  If a command exists by that name, the word is     replaced
> by the full pathname of the command.

Thus:

```
%echo =ls
/bin/ls
```

Comment: +1 https://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_15.html#:~:text=If%20a%20word%20begins%20with,the%20text%20of%20the%20alias.